# Action Mailer around_action call back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have this,

```
class SiteMailer < ApplicationMailer
around_action :set_sales

 def notify_customer(site)
   @site = site
 end

private

 def set_sales
   @sales ||= @site.customer.sales
 end
end
```

Is it possible to set the values for `@sales` as shown above? I tried but couldn't succeed. Can anyone help me or make this clear. Searched over previous questions on this topic and found people using `around_action` for exception handling only. Can't we use `around_action` like this?

Comment: You want to send mail, which contains site data, right? do you want to send sales data too?

Comment: Yes, I want to set the sales and use @sales from .html.erb files

Comment: can you provide your model and controller code as well as your mailer html file?

Comment: I have SiteNotifiable which is included in the site model. So site notifiable triggers the Sitemailer.notify_customer(site).deliver_later. Similarly my site notifiable triggers several other emails which pass site as an argument. So in Site mailer, I initialise @site = site in each mailer method. But I also need sales, since sales are common for all as it is obtained as follows: sales = site.customer.sales. So I wanna use around_action to set the sales for all the method in the site mailer class.

Comment: I have posted an answer look into it.
If you have any problems regrading this. Leave a comment.

Comment: **So I wanna use around_action to set the sales for all the method in the site mailer class**. Why it has to be `around_action`? Why not just `before_action`?

Comment: I too tried `before_action` and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

try on mailer folder:

**yourfilename.html.erb**

```
<p> lorem ipsum <%= @site %>!</p>
<p> lorem ipsum <%= @sales %>!</p>
```

On model **site.rb**

```
class Site < ApplicationRecord
.............
protected
  after_commit :set_sales, on: [:update #your action]
  def set_sales
    site = self.site
    sales = site.customer.sales
    SiteMailer.notify_customer(site, sales).deliver_now
  end
end
```

..............................

```
class SiteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def notify_customer(site, sales)
    @site = site
    @sales = sales
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this but I want to avoid code repetition in my views files. I have around 68 views files with a different language. So I don't want to do <%= site.customer.sales %> in each file. I want to do <%= @sales %>. To achieve this I want to set the sales in SiteMailer and use it in all the view files. I can set sales under SiteMailer for each method but I don't want this as well, I want to user ActionMailer callbacks like around_action to set the sales so that it can be re-used.